# How to control the gaps between different size grid items?

Tags: css, css-grid

In the following layout, I would like A and B to be juxtaposed, and all the gap forced by D be between B & C. Justify/align-content/self/items don't seem to have any effect. Nor does grid-gap.

While these items have fixed sizes, the general problem does not: the items may have various widths. When D is narrower than A + B, they are juxtaposed, but when D is wider than A + B, I can't figure out how to keep A and B juxtaposed.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a b c" "d d e";
  width: min-content;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
  width: 120px;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
  width: 40px;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
  width: 80px;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
  width: 300px;
}

.e {
  grid-area: e;
  width: 100px;
}

.a,
.b,
.c,
.d,
.e {
  justify-self: start;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1>floating grid items</h1>
<div class=container>
  <div class=a>A</div>
  <div class=b>B</div>
  <div class=c>C</div>
  <div class=d>D</div>
  <div class=e>E</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a template column where you set the first one to auto and the second one to `1fr`. You can also consider `inline-grid` instead of setting the width to `min-content`

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "a b c" 
    "d d e";
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr auto;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
  width: 120px;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
  width: 40px;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
  width: 80px;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
  width: 300px;
}

.e {
  grid-area: e;
  width: 100px;
}

.a,
.b,
.c,
.d,
.e {
  justify-self: start;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1>floating grid items</h1>
<div class=container>
  <div class=a>A</div>
  <div class=b>B</div>
  <div class=c>C</div>
  <div class=d>D</div>
  <div class=e>E</div>
</div>
```

Or you can consider `max-content` in the width and keep `display:grid`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "a b c" 
    "d d e";
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr auto;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:max-content;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
  width: 120px;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
  width: 40px;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
  width: 80px;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
  width: 300px;
}

.e {
  grid-area: e;
  width: 100px;
}

.a,
.b,
.c,
.d,
.e {
  justify-self: start;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1>floating grid items</h1>
<div class=container>
  <div class=a>A</div>
  <div class=b>B</div>
  <div class=c>C</div>
  <div class=d>D</div>
  <div class=e>E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now that's really interesting! But if I leave it as display:grid; and width:min-content; I wind up with E overlapping D! That is a real surprise! Hmm. Your solution has blank space after E.  I see that grid-template-columns:auto 1fr auto; eliminates that. Looks like 1fr only helps if this situation only occurs once.  And not sure why using inline-grid is a requirement to get this to work, but it seems to be.

Comment: @Victoria the calculation of min-content is a bit complex .. using inline-grid will make it automatically shrink to fit the content. And you are right, you can replace the last 1fr with auto to remove the gap. didn't really pay attention to that last gap

Comment: @Victoria check the update, I also added another example where max-content is what you need with display:grid

Comment: But I only want one of these on a line, and inline-grid allows multiple (if they fit). I suppose I could wrap them in a <div>, but that has a bad feel. I wonder why min-content seems to interact adversely with 1fr.

Comment: @Victoria you are wrongly thinking that min-content is what you need. You are looking for max-content. It's a bit tricky to explain, will try to add more details later

Comment: That max-content one blows my mind! But it seems to do the job, in the example. I haven't figured out how to get it to work in my real code yet... which already has a grid-template-columns, and I think this situation only occurs in one column-group per grid, but figuring out exactly how to fit this in is harder than my brain can handle tonight. Will try in the morning.

Comment: I picked min-content because I didn't want to stretch to fill the page, but max-content tries to put all the inner text on one line of each grid element... so I've generally avoided max-content. But in this case, it might work.

Comment: Couldn't quit. Figured out the right combination... the right column for 1fr and definitely requires max-content to work. I look forward to more details. Thanks!

Comment: @Victoria are you sure the right column? it should be the middle one. At least based on the code you shared. Probably your real code is different

Comment: I got it fully integrated into my real code. It is a different column in each grid, but can be determined. I tried hard to generalize it so it could work with more than one column in a grid that might have different sizes, even though I don't need that for this application, but failed. Thanks again. Wish I understood it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid-column-gap` if you want horisontal and `grid-row-gap` if you want vertical gap.

Put it on element which has `display: grid`.

Also I don't suggest using grid. It is not well supported. You can check it out [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid). I would suggest switching to flex tho.

Hope it helped :)

**UPDATE**
You did this

`grid-template-areas: "a b c" "d d e";` and then you put `grid-area: a; grid-area: b; grid-area: c; grid-area: d; grid-area: e;` which mean that fifth one is empty.

Next.. Display grid will arrange items in this order 
| | |
| | |

If you have items like this

```
|a|a|
|as|a|
```

grid will display them like this

```
|a |a|
|as|a|
```

because it follows that line between items. If you want to make it look different you should use flex

Look it up [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: It depends. Do you want to support IE? If you do then go for flex. At least I found it easier to make a website with flex to support IE

And if answer helped you, could you accept it so it can help to the others too

Comment: grid-column-gap:0; has no effect on this, as noted in the quesiton. Or if it can, show me how.

Comment: True. It has.. But a lot less then grid. And all those bugs can we avoided. I actually did a quite big website with flex and it had to support IE. It works very well.

Comment: Sorry you have to support IE. Grid is well supported on browsers I care about. I have many more rows and columns in my actual grid, and flex can't do the job. This is just a stripped-down demonstration of the issue. While you edited your text, it would be better to show me a snippet that works, if grid-column-gap will work. I couldn't get it to.

Comment: It won't work in your case. You just can't break ```grid``` layout that way. Gap property will only make gap between elements bigger or smaller. It is 0 by default. 

Also.. D is wider becase you have this layout  ```grid-template-areas: "a b c" "d d e";``` and you assigned letter D to both d's in ```grid-template-areas```. It occupies both so that's why it is wider. You can change it by writing another letter to it. Like this
```grid-template-areas: "a b c" "d e f";```

Comment: So if I did that, then b would be on top of e and c would be on top of f. That would ruin the layout in other ways. All I want to do is move B to the left next to A. There is no constraint on where B is, but it seems grid centers it in the space, regardless of any justify or align settings.

Comment: well you can give it ```width: 100%``` to first one and it will be aligned with B